# How to get value of HttpResponseMessage like HttpStatusCode Using Koush ION

Tags: android, http-headers, http-response-codes

Here is How I returned HttpResponseMessage from my ASP.net server like

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"some string");
```

And I have accessed the returned response in android with [Kaush ION](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/ion) like this

```
Ion.with(LoginActivity.this)
                    .load("--URL TO POST--")
                    .setJsonObjectBody(jsonToSubmit)
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .withResponse()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                            //I want to access header information here
                         }
```

Inside `onCompleted` Method I can easily access `HttpStatusCode` like

```
int code = result.getHeaders().code();
```

**OR**

```
String statusCode = result.getHeaders().message();
```

**Now My Question is :**

**How can I get that "some string" which was sent in `HttpResponseMessage` with `HttpStatusCode` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

----Here is the solution-----

**Create a model class StringMsg.cs**

```
public class StringMsg
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**If you want to send string message and want to retrieve that send it like**

```
StringMsg str = new StringMsg();
str.Message = "some string";
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, str);
```

**Finally, Retrieve The String in `onCompleted` Method like this**

```
 @Override
  public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {

      JsonObject result1 = result.getResult();
      String myResult = result1.get("Message"); // Result

   }
```